# Concord Grape Vine Pruning

Tags: pruning, grape-vine

I am in year two of establishing a Concord grape vine according to the Four-Arm Kniffen system at my home in New Jersey, and I have a couple of questions related to pruning.  I planted the vine in spring 2022, and I had established a strong trunk and 6-8 inch horizontal shoots for both of the lower arms by the fall of 2022.  At present (mid-June 2023) those two lower shoots have now grown out to about 32 inches and 14-16 buds each.  Each shoot also has one bunch of emerging grapes (picture of one attached) within the first 6-8 inches that were established by fall 2022.

I've read conflicting accounts, so I would appreciate input on the following two questions:

1. Should I prune the two developing grape bunches from the horizontal shoots?  I read one source that said I should do so because having grape growth in the second year will draw energy from the development of the root system.
2. And is now the time to tip those 32-inch horizontal shoots back to 10 buds at most?  I don't know if that should be done at this time of year or whether I should wait until the end of the season or the start of next spring.

Thanks for any help the community might have to offer!

[image]